# Gmail can't redirect to particular account

Tags: gmail

When I want redirect to particular Gmail account it is not working for me if other account login it just open inbox of that account not ask for particular account.
I have try with this
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=myemail@gmail.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/myemail@gmail.com/

Answer (score 1):

Gmail automatically detects if there is another session. Unless you have that, it won't ask you